# How to get server ssh keys on debian ec2 instance?

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2

I launched an instance on EC2 with a [Debian 7.6 AMI](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Wheezy) and the system log is empty.  Is that by design?  With the ubuntu images, the server's ssh keys were accessible via the system log.  What is the procedure for verifying the server fingerprint on debian?  Must I generate and add my own key, with user data?  I'd sure prefer not to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case here, but frequently the console logs take 10-15 minutes to appear on the web console or be available via the EC2 API.

Comment: @EEAA I waited almost an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/andsens/bootstrap-vz/issues/136) in the debian HVM images.

Answer (score 0):

Presumming you are talking about the ssh host key (and not keys for user accounts).

I suppose it depends on how the installation was performed.  Most Linux systems will generate new ssh host keys when sshd is initially started.  Interesting in that I thought these keys were in a specific file and not contained in any log file.  Perhaps the ssh package was not automatically installed with that version of the instance?

BTW, ssh keys (public and private) for specific accounts would need to be manually generated and installed.

Comment: The other ec2 images I've worked with (ubuntu and coreos) log the ssh host key (or its fingerprint) in the system logs when it is generated so that the user can retrieve it securely from aws.  The problem here isn't merely that part of the log missing, which might result if the ssh package were inexplicably absent.  The whole log is empty or inaccessible.

Comment: The ssh keys for the default user are configured before launch and injected by ec2.